# Gnus BCC to appropriate sending address

Tags: email, emacs, smtp, archive, gnus

Gmail is wonderful in that anything sent with that SMTP will be saved in the "sent" folder online; unfortunately, none of my other email servers provide this. My intent, then, is to automatically add a Bcc to whatever email address I'm sending from. but I could use some help in adjusting my .gnus to do this. Here's what I have in  my .gnus:

```lisp
; includes reply-to with whoever an incoming mail was sent to
    (setq gnus-posting-styles
      '(((header "to" "me1@gmail.com")
         (address "me1@gmail.com"))
    ((header "to" "me2@gmail.com")
         (address "me2@gmail.com"))
    ((header "to" "me@univ.edu")
         (address "me@univ.edu"))
    ((header "to" "me1@mysite.com")
         (address "me1@mysite.com"))
    ((header "to" "me2@mysite.com")
         (address "me2@mysite.com"))
    ((header "cc" "me1@gmail.com")
         (address "me1@gmail.com"))
    ((header "cc" "me2@gmail.com")
         (address "me2@gmail.com"))
    ((header "cc" "me@univ.edu")
         (address "me@univ.edu"))
    ((header "cc" "me1@mysite.com")
         (address "me1@mysite.com"))
    ((header "cc" "me2@mysite.com")
         (address "me2@mysite.com"))
))
```

How can set it to BCC whatever email I am using besides gmail? And is there a way to do this on a new message where the from address is specified at send-time, not at creation-time?

Comment: Within the library `sendmail.el`, see the variable `mail-self-blind`.  See also the functions:  `mail-bcc`; and `mail-fcc` (which requires that a folder be specified).

Comment: Hmm... I've looked, and tried `(setq mail-self-blind t)` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Are you using `M-x compose-mail` to start the process?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *partial* answer:

This goes in the `init.el` or `.emacs` file:

```
(setq mail-user-agent 'sendmail-user-agent)

(setq mail-self-blind t)

(setq user-mail-address "WorldsEndless@stackoverflow.com")
```

Then, `M-x compose-email`

---

**ALTERNATIVE**:  Insert the bcc whenever desired.  I have added `mail-send-and-exit` so that it is possible to do everything at the time of sending if that is what the user prefers.  The function `worldsendless-mail-bcc` can be further customized to give the user options for selecting different bcc email addresses that are predetermined, or it can be more complex such as looking to see who it is from (i.e., examine the sender email account) to choose a bcc based upon the sender.

```
(setq mail-bcc "WorldsEndless@stackoverflow.com")

(defun worldsendless-mail-bcc ()
  "Move point to end of BCC field, creating it if necessary."
  (interactive)
  (expand-abbrev)
  (or (mail-position-on-field "bcc" t)
      (progn (mail-position-on-field "to")
       (insert (concat "\nBCC: " mail-bcc) )))
  (mail-send-and-exit))
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to archive all sent messages on a sending per-email address basis? Look at the "Archived Messages" section of the Gnus manual.

Comment: Archive, yes, but not on my hard drive--on the server of the email address I'm sending from.